# Detect onClose multiple select in Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I want to create a filter with a multiple select, that when is closed it refresh the page with the new parameters.

So basically I want to capture the onClose event of the select.

I can detect when an option is selected/deselected with

```
$("#test").on('change', function() {
     console.log($(this).val())
});
```

but I don't want this, since it would reload the page everytime a user change the value. I want to reload the page when the user is done and click "outside" of the select.

Complete code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXQvNB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch the `close` event on the class `select-dropdown`:

```
$('.select-dropdown').on('close', function() {
   // ...
});
```

[**Updated codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XayGgw)

Comment: Thanks, this kinda works. I tried it on my project but it seems that whenever I click outside of the select it triggers the event, but this doesn't happen in Codepen. Any idea why?

The code is the same

Comment: The behaviour is the same in the codepen, and on any other code playground like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmew9rcn/). When do you want to trigger the event then since you say that u want it "outside" of the select?

Comment: The codepen you gave me is perfect, and it's exactly what I want. 
I was wondering why in my project the event is triggering always. For example i reload the page and I click anywhere (without clicking the select first) and the event triggers.

Comment: Sorry, found the problem! 
I was using the version 0.98.2 of materialize.js and not the 0.100.2, now it works perfectly. 
Example of the problem with 0.98.2: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXQvNB?editors=1111

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on the close event,do you mid sharing a link.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can write resize event on ul like this

```
$('#select-options-d19b3203-929c-cb39-29c4-6170613be5d7').resize( function() {
  alert("Closed.");
 });
```